# Numpy exports column headings to csv improperly

Tags: python, numpy, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

The I wrote some code to scrape data off of a web page and put it in csv format, but the end result isn't what I want. The figures/values are handled properly, but the column headings aren't. Here's what I mean:

[image]

Above is how it looks in the spreadsheet.

[image]

And this is how it looks in a text editor. I don't understand what's wrong because when I open the array in Spyder it looks alright:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
from numpy import array, insert, transpose, savetxt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from requests import get
from csv import writer


def obtain_links():
    data = {"inflation":get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/inflrates.asp").text,
            "crude_oil":get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/DailyCrude.asp").text,
            "for_res":get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/IntOps/Reserve.asp").text,
            "exch":get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/").text,
            "m_market":get("https://www.cbn.gov.ng/rates/mnymktind.asp").text}
    return data

data = obtain_links()

def parse_inf(data=data):
    
    html = bs(data["inflation"],"lxml")
    
    year = html.find("td",width="62%").find("h2").text
    
    months = html.find("div",id="ContentTextinner").find_all("th")
    
    inf_months = [i.text for i in months]
    inf_months = [f"{i} {year}" for i in inf_months]
    inf_months[0] = inf_months[0][:5]
    inf_months = array(inf_months).transpose()
    
    measure = html.find("div",id="ContentTextinner").find_all("td",align="left")
    measure = [i.text for i in measure][:-3]
    
    values = [[i.text[:5] for i in html.find("div",id="ContentTextinner").find_all("td",class_="style2",style="width: 15%")],
              [i.text[:5] for i in html.find("div",id="ContentTextinner").find_all("td",class_="style2",style="width: 16%")],
              [i.text[:5] for i in html.find("div",id="ContentTextinner").find_all("td",class_="style2",width="20%")]]
    values.insert(0,measure)
    values = array(values)
    
    inf_data = insert(values,0,inf_months,axis=1)
    return inf_data

inf_data = parse_inf()

savetxt("/home/user/Documents/Scraped Data/Inflation Data.csv",inf_data,fmt="%s",delimiter=",")
```

Any ideas chaps and chappettes?

Comment: Remove the newline `\n` character from the column titles before writing it to a CSV.

Comment: The original didn't have any newline characters. But just in case, I changed the `measure` variable to `measure = [i.text.strip() for i in measure][:-3]`. However, the problem persists.

Comment: `measure = [i.text.replace("\n", "") for i in measure][:-3]` this is what you need.

Comment: Worked like magic. Thanks.